# CSS 3 Shape cut out circle

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to create this shape:

[image]

is this even possible with CSS without images?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Have you any idea how ?

Comment: Google 'CSS shapes'.

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Muhammad_Usman/e7o6cogy/)